# Windows 10 Explorer: Quick access pinned item limit

Tags: windows-10-quick-access

Now my Windows 10 only shows 50 items of pinned quick access items which I added by drag a folder to the expanded quick access list on the navigation bar. What is the registry entry to control this?

Here is an existing question that have the same title but a different real question: [Change number of items in Quick Access](https://superuser.com/questions/954579/change-number-of-items-in-quick-access)

Comment: Are you saying that you are currently limited to 50 items in your Quick Access? What does drag a folder have to do with this?

Comment: @music2myear  yes. I mention that to make it clear that all the items in my Quick Access is added manually in that way, there is no automatic "recent items" in the list.